# Failure in before hook:BaseSteps.setUp() Message: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError

Tags: maven, bdd

I know this had multiple solutions and I tried all, it didnt work for me.

This is my pom.xml, I have added the exclusions tag which in warning told me that this dependencies might also use slf4j.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.walmartlabs.ern.webpos2.0-Tablet_Automation</groupId>
<artifactId>webpos2.0-Tablet_Automation</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>POSAutomation</name>
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
<distributionManagement>
    <site>
        <id>proximity</id>
        <url>dav:https://repository.walmart.com/content/sites/CoSTL/qa-automation/</url>
    </site>
</distributionManagement>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.fortysix</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-postman-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>0.1.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.walmart</groupId>
        <artifactId>plexus-client</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.59</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.walmart.qe</groupId>
        <artifactId>jira-xray-testrunner</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sourceforge.javacsv</groupId>
        <artifactId>javacsv</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jcraft</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsch</artifactId>
        <version>0.1.53</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.5</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.masterthought/cucumber-reporting -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
        <version>4.10.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.mkolisnyk</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-runner</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
        <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20140107</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-picocontainer</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.5</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-bundle-jaxrs</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-jdk14</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-nop</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>gossip</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jcabi</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcabi-log</artifactId>
        <version>0.16</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.saxon</groupId>
        <artifactId>Saxon-HE</artifactId>
        <version>9.8.0-7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.galenframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>galen-java-support</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.6</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <extensions>
        <extension>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.wagon</groupId>
            <artifactId>wagon-webdav-jackrabbit</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </extension>
    </extensions>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>ch.fortysix</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-postman-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.1.6</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>Report Generation</id>
                    <phase>test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>send-mail</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <inherited>true</inherited>
                    <configuration>
                        <!-- From Email address -->
                        <from>a0r01ox@homeoffice.wal-mart.com</from>
                        <!-- Email subject -->
                        <subject>Cucumber Test Automation Report</subject>
                        <!-- Fail the build if the mail doesn't reach -->
                        <failonerror>false</failonerror>
                        <!-- Email Body Content -->
                        <htmlMessage>
                            <![CDATA[
                                <p>New test build triggered!</p>
                                <p>Attached html file contains the test result status</p>
                                ]]>
                        </htmlMessage>
                        <!-- host -->
                        <mailhost>walmart.com</mailhost>
                        <!-- port of the host -->
                        <mailport>465</mailport>
                        <mailssl>true</mailssl>
                        <mailAltConfig>true</mailAltConfig>
                        <!-- Email Authentication(Username and Password) -->
                        <mailuser>a0r01ox@homeoffice.wal-mart.com</mailuser>
                        <mailpassword></mailpassword>
                        <receivers>
                            <!-- To Email address -->
                            <receiver>a0r01ox@homeoffice.wal-mart.com</receiver>
                            <receiver>a0r01ox@homeoffice.wal-mart.com</receiver>
                        </receivers>
                        <fileSets>
                            <fileSet>
                                <!-- Report directory Path -->
                                <directory>${basedir}/target</directory>
                                <includes>
                                    <!-- Report file name -->
                                    <include>cucumber-test-results.html</include>
                                </includes>
                            </fileSet>
                        </fileSets>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
            <version>4.11.2</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>execution</id>
                    <phase>verify</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <projectName>CoSTL-Tablet_Automation</projectName>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/cucumber-report-html</outputDirectory>
                        <cucumberOutput>${project.build.directory}/cucumber.json</cucumberOutput>
                        <jsonFiles>
                            <param>${project.build.directory}/cucumber.json</param>
                        </jsonFiles>
                        <enableFlashCharts>false</enableFlashCharts>
                        <buildNumber>${project.version}</buildNumber>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>attach-sources</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>jar</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <!--<plugin> -->
        <!--<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId> -->
        <!--<artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId> -->
        <!--<version>2.19.1</version> -->
        <!--</plugin> -->
    </plugins>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <!--This plugin's configuration is used to store Eclipse m2e settings 
                only. It has no influence on the Maven build itself. -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                        <pluginExecutions>
                            <pluginExecution>
                                <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <groupId>
                                        com.github.temyers
                                    </groupId>
                                    <artifactId>
                                        cucumber-jvm-parallel-plugin
                                    </artifactId>
                                    <versionRange>
                                        [1.0.1,)
                                    </versionRange>
                                    <goals>
                                        <goal>generateRunners</goal>
                                    </goals>
                                </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                <action>
                                    <ignore></ignore>
                                </action>
                            </pluginExecution>
                        </pluginExecutions>
                    </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.7.1</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

This is my error:

```
Failure in before hook:BaseSteps.setUp()
Message: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.slf4j.spi.LocationAwareLogger.log(Lorg/slf4j/Marker;Ljava/lang/String;ILjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Throwable;)V
at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLocationAwareLog.debug(SLF4JLocationAwareLog.java:120)
```

Can anyone please help me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Not all of those artifacts are in central, so I can't download your project, but my guess would be that you're mixing versions of slf4j.

Try something like

```
mvn dependency:tree | grep -i slf4j
```